# How to access Metal Gear Solid V Phantom Pain true multiplayer?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I've played MGSV's FOB infiltration multiplayer. But that isn't what I consider true multiplayer because it's just playing against computer controlled AI.

I've seen people play true multiplayer, where you shoot at characters controlled by real people:

. I just can't figure out which menu to access this mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Metal Gear Online from the main menu, when you first start up the game.
Additionally, there's a setting in the options menu that lets you choose which game mode to launch when starting the game.